# AngularJs Simple Edit

Tags: angularjs

I was following a tutorial to get the basic understanding of angularjs. In my case edit link does not load back the object properties to textbox. Please let me know what i am doing wrong here is the code and fiddle

```
<body>
<div class="scope" data-ng-app="mymodule" data-ng-controller="mycontroller">
    <h3>AngularJS Filter data sample </h3>
    <br />
    Name:<br /> 
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="Name" /><br />
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="Position" /><br />
    <button data-ng-click="addfriend()"> Add Friend</button>
    <br />
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="Namesearch" /><br />
    <ul>
        <li class="li" data-ng-repeat="element in friendlist | filter:Namesearch | orderBy:'Name'">
            <strong> [{{$index + 1}}] {{ element.Name | uppercase}} working as {{ element.Position}}  </strong>
            [ <a href="#" ng-click="clearUser(element)">clear</a>
            | <a href="#" ng-click="removeUser(element)">X</a>
            | <a href="#" ng-click="editUser(1)">edit</a>
            ]
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
```

And the JS code

```
var mymodule = angular.module('mymodule', [])
mymodule.controller('mycontroller', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.friendlist =
        [{ Name: 'Zia', Position: 'AM' }, { Name: 'Zia1', Position: 'PM' }, { Name: 'Zia2', Position: 'GM' }
        ];

    $scope.editUser = function (id) {

        for (i in $scope.friendlist) {
            if ($scope.friendlist[i].Name == 'Zia') {

                $scope.newFriend = angular.copy($scope.friendlist[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}]);
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t1525ck5/10/)

and also I want to know the significance of  `class="scope"` in first `div`

Comment: I dont see the fiddle link

Comment: `for (i in $scope.friendlist) {` - Use a regular `for` loop when iterating an array - `for..in` is meant for iterating objects properties.

Comment: Try removing href from your anchor tag or add a preventDefault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this solve your question? http://jsfiddle.net/3hv7y369/

In the inputs you need `newFriend.Name` and `newFriend.Position` to show the copied values. I also finished the `editUser()` function to work with every user.

Comment: and How to update changed value to show in list again

Comment: I advise you make a 'save' button which copies the values to the corresponding entry in `$scope.friendlist`. This automatically updates the displayed list.